How to select objects by face count
As in the title, we need to select objects that have a given number of faces or greater / less than X number of faces. I got the solution delivered by ChatGPT and tested in Blender 4.0, so I'm posting it below as an answer:

This code selects objects with face count equal 1:
import bpy

# Iterate through all objects in the scene
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    # Check if the object is a mesh
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        # Get the number of faces
        face_count = len(obj.data.polygons)
        # Check if the mesh has exactly one face
        if face_count == 1:
            # Select the object
            obj.select_set(True)

Alternatively, we can specify a range for face count, where we'd replace 8th line with:
        if 1 <= face_count <= 10:
and then it will select all objects with face count between 1 and 10.
I'm glad if this helps anyone.
